# using sqlite ORDERBY field

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I have a database that I want to sort but I dont really understand how to use the ORDER BY field when I query. the only thing I have done with it is sort a column using `ASC` or `DEC` but beyond that I dont know how to use is.

what I want to do is when I query the database I want to sort it by a column that holds a number in milliseconds from the one that is the closest to the current time `ie. system.currentTimeMills() - timeInDb` to the one that is the furthest away.

anyone want to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by a specified column.

The ORDER BY keyword sort the records in ascending order by default.

If you want to sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.

For eg:

```
SELECT * FROM timeRecordTable
ORDER BY timeInDb DESC
```

will order rows by descending order, which is what you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT timeInDb FROM timeRecordTable ORDERBY timeInDb DESC;`

Or if you need other fields than

`SELECT * FROM timeRecordTable ORDERBY timeInDb DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM MY_DB ORDER BY time_column DESC`

will get all the items from your database, and order them by date, the latest items being at the top of your results.